# calendar date getting back -1 day, what is wrong, alternate solution?

Tags: php, date, calendar

I'm trying to go back one day in the calendar – What am I doing wrong?

**My approach:**

```php
$weekdays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
///////
function getDates($year) {
  $dates = array();
  date("L", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 7, $year)) ? $days = 366 : $days = 365;
  ///
  for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
    // get Unix timestamp for a date
    $month = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, $i, $year));
    $wk = date('W', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, $i, $year));
    $wkDay = date('D', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, $i, $year));
    $day = date('d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, $i, $year));
    ///
    $dates[$month][$wk][$wkDay] = $day;
  }
  return $dates;
}
//////
$year = 2020; // from this Year
$dates = getDates($year);
$countW = 1; // for counting weeks
// Output code
echo '<h2><span>Calendar '.$year.'</span></h2>';
foreach($dates as $month => $weeks) {
  echo '<div>';
    echo '<table>';
      echo '<caption>'.$year.' '.$month.'</caption>';
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>W</th>';
        echo '<th>'.implode('</th><th>', $weekdays).'</th>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach ($weeks as $week => $days){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$countW++.'</td>';
        foreach ($weekdays as $day) {
          echo '<td>';
            /* I'm overwhelmed here! */
            echo isset($days[$day]) ? $days[$day] : date('d', strtotime('-1 day')); // outputted is 5
          echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
      }
      echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

*I tried the following codes:*

- `date('d', strtotime('-1 day')) // outputted: 5 (today is 6)`
- `$jd = gregoriantojd(01,06,2020); echo jddayofweek($jd,2); // outputted: Mon (today is Tue)`

> With this code I get the day from the **current** day before.
>   It is expected the day before the **specified** day

**what is happening**

[image: what is happening]

**is expected**

[image]

Comment: Why do you use mktime?

Comment: @Dharman I use mktime several times! Which one?

Comment: All of them. Why use this archaic function? What kind of use case do you have for it instead of DateTime class?

Comment: @Dharman i have no idea how to solve this better.

Comment: I'm quite sure there are complete calendar library's on GitHub. I understand the joy of Makin it yourself, but in some cases it's better to use what exist

Comment: @Andreas true, but that's how I can learn. If only I could solve this problem ... And I still can't handle classes.

Comment: if you can't "handle" classes you aren't going to get very far in programming. Maybe now is the moment to learn.

Comment: @ADyson you're right, but that doesn't help me right now.

Comment: well it probably would actually, because you could likely implement your requirement much more easily using the DateTime class.

Answer (score 0):

> With this code I get the day from the **current** day before. It is expected the day before the **specified** day

The day that is "specified" here `date('d', strtotime('-1 day'))` *is* the current day.

Generally speaking, a (American) monthly calendar will leave a blank space if the day is not in the month. For example:

[image]

That would be a super simple fix to the problem. If not, you'll need to adjust your thinking (and the code!). In the case of the first week of January, the dates for Mon and Tues are -2 and -1 from *the first day of January*. Similarly, in the last week they are -2 and -1 from the first day of February (or +1, +2 from the *last* day of January).